# Core features required for an Agile project management app

Tags: agile

Can you agile gurus go through at a high level, what features an agile project management application should have?

Comment: SO is not a requirements gathering tool.

Answer (score 3):

A good starting point would be an existing Agile project management application, like

> [**Mingle** from Thoughtworks](http://studios.thoughtworks.com/mingle-agile-project-management)

IMO they qualify as 'agile gurus' :-)

From a personal perspective, I'd say the key to Agile project management is being able to aggregate stories/use-cases/units-of-work (user-contributed) with team progress/feedback (developer-contributed). I think existing tools (say, Microsoft Project) fail here because they are 'static' time-management tools rather than dynamic representations of the current iteration and the backlog/remaining work.
If you are not measuring velocity and quality you probably don't really know how your Agile project is going - so you want a tool that helps do that, rather than just a tool that tracks the time people work on stuff.

It's a pretty open-ended question though... why do you ask? Are you planning to build one, or are you looking for criteria to help buy one?

Edit: also, your tool choice is probably dictated by your technology platform - Team Foundation's work items and plug-in methodologies (see Cochango's Scrum plugin) can arguably be described as an Agile project management tool. But that doesn't help if you're using Java/Eclipse and want Jira or something to do it for you.

Comment: Also checkout Rally's product, and to a lesser extent, Danube's ScrumWorks.

Answer (score 1):

An agile project management application should have:

- A shrubbery;
- an ejector seat;
- a recycling toilet;
- a user inteface;
- maybe a database; and
- a Cherry on top.

But seriously... Agile really is just another work process... Team planning (Gantt charts), a minimal workflow engine, communications, general record-keeping, recording estimates verses actuals... It's all pretty well covered by existing software (and thats one of the reasons Agile took-off).

Cheers. Keith.

Answer (score 0):

The core elements would be requirements management, release/iteration management, kanban wall, burn down charts.  I'm currently using the app 'Bright Green Projects' - http://www.brightgreenprojects.com

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a good story management tool. You can get inspiration from these guys.

http://www.pivotaltracker.com/